# Loading a pretrained model from torch.hub in Sagemaker

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytorch, amazon-sagemaker

I'm getting an import error when trying to load a pretrained resnet50 model in Sagemaker Studio. I'm using the provided Pytorch 2.0.0 Python 3.10 GPU optimized image on a t3.medium. My code:

```
import torch

model = torch.hub.load("pytorch/vision", "resnet50", weights="IMAGENET1K_V2")
```

Resulting in: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch._custom_ops'

I can workaround by instead using the torchvision api, but I'm curious about what the issue is for torch.hub

Answer (score 0):

The `torch._custom_ops` module is used for GPU-based operations (CUDA) in PyTorch. This error is caused by a mismatch between the instance you have selected, and the chosen image.

The [t3.medium](https://instances.vantage.sh/aws/ec2/t3.medium) instances do *not* have a GPU, so you'll need to retry your code with a CPU-optimised image.

Alternatively, if you wish to use a GPU instance, see [SageMaker Studio Instances with GPUs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks-available-instance-types.html#notebooks-resources-gpu).

You can click on the below button, and select a GPU-based instance (e.g. `ml.g4dn.xlarge`).

[image]